# Is there a way to "rescue" mesh that has very bad topology?

Tags: modeling, topology

I have a mesh with tons of ngons, non-manfold stuff, poles, and a decent amount of tris.
Should I just give up on the mesh, or can I somehow rescue it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To deal with bad topology, but not having to start from scratch, It makes sense creating a new mesh and **retopologizing**. That is: using some form of vertex/edge/face snapping and/or a shrinkwrap modifier, you trace and receate your old mesh using proper topology. This technique is also useful when sculpting at a high poly count and then re-creating the mesh with less polygons.

It sounds daunting but in reality it is not a big deal at all.

Here are a few links that might help:

- https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/tutorials/retopologize-nine-times-faster-shrink-wrap-modifier-blender
- https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/retopology.html
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eaqYqkjimD8

Comment: see also http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6253/how-to-convert-from-high-poly-to-low-poly/6407#6407

Comment: And https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45460/where-is-that-new-retopo-feature

Answer (score 5):

There is also a modifier called the [*remesh* modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.62/Remesh_Modifier), which does a sort of automatic retopology. I don't recommend it if you need clean, efficient topology, as it's often required to turn up the octree depth rather high, which can result in a dense mesh.

However, it's quite useful when you need a quick way to e.g. get a boolean operation to work or make volume rendering happy.

Comment: my computer crashes before its clean with remesh since i ahve many hole and stuff :D

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it can help to just *[Remove Doubles](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html#remove-doubles)*.

In edit mode, choose edge select mode and type <kbd>A</kbd> once or twice to select all edges. Then just hit <kbd>W</kbd> and choose *Remove Doubles*.

In my case, I had simply deleted opposing faces and bridged the remaining edges. Removing doubles fixed the Bevel modifier not working.

Comment: Remove doubles functionality has been removed in recent versions.