# Where is that new retopo feature?

Tags: mesh, topology

I heard/saw there is a retopo engine in blender now. Is this true? I cannot seem to find it, and the google results I get are either old stuff (I'm already using magnet/snap) or a marketed plugin.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several options available. You can take a look at the Instant Field Aligned Meshes for remeshing (http://igl.ethz.ch/projects/instant-meshes/), Mira and Mifth Tools (http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?366107-MiraTools) and there is the Iceking Tools.

I have the paid addon that you are referring to, retopoflow, and it is worth it - but if you search online you will find the github page as well anyway since it is GPL if you want to try that, too.

Comment: Very good and helpful, thank you very much.