# Best way to cleanup these messy edges?

Tags: mesh, faces, edges, geometry

I want to cleanup the highlighted vertices so they are rather sharp edges (which can then be beveled with a modifier if I wish). I've tried just selecting those vertices and doing remove doubles, limited dissolve, and decimate, but each time it ends up affecting the non-highlighted parts (the faces which I want to keep smooth). 
[image: bevels from hell]

Here's another example. I want to clean up the edges without losing the roundness of the pegs:
[image: more bevels from hell]

This is what I ended up with for the first picture:
[image: bevels from purgatory]

Comment: That is some messy topology...I think re-topologizing the whole object might be a lot less work than trying to fix it.

Comment: I've never done that before. Something like described here? https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/tutorials/retopologize-nine-times-faster-shrink-wrap-modifier-blender

Comment: Related [Is there a way to “rescue” mesh that has very bad topology?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18203/is-there-a-way-to-rescue-mesh-that-has-very-bad-topology/18204#18204)

Comment: Curiously, if I use shrinkwrap with a high subsurface count on the sphere, it keeps the messy edges I'm trying to get rid of. If I use it with a low subsurface count, it doesn't keep enough detail...

Comment: I ened up doing a pretty decent cleanup job by using decimate on discrete features, like one loop at a time. In the first picture above, there are 4 loops, and if I decimate them one at a time I could get each one down to 30-60 vertices.

Comment: @Matt Chambers - You may want to consider an approach like [img]https://i.imgur.com/lfqChg9.png[/img] in the future.