# How can we remove overlapping edges?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges, bmesh

I am cleaning up a friend's model and often run into this problem: Often, there are multiple edges of various lengths overlapping along the same line. Below is a visual example:
[image: A picture of three lines/edges of different lengths.]
...that overlap to cause:
[image: A picture of four vertices in a line, with darker portions representing overlapping edges.]
...as opposed to the desired:
[image: A picture of four vertices in a line, with a lack of darker portions representing the lack of overlapping edges.]
I was wondering if there was an easy way to clean up edges like this without manually deleting the offending edges and reconnecting the relevant vertices?

[image: A picture of a Blender gun barrel with an example of overlapping edges.]

Comment: I agree that redoing the mesh might be best. Overlapping edges like this often result from depthless extrusions (right-clicking after applying an extrusion, which doesn't cancel the operation) or repeated boolean operations without cleaning the result (merging vertices, deleting unwanted components). You can kindly remind your friend about these hazards and how to avoid them.

Comment: Use dissolve edges... but poorly planned topology (like the mess that you have in front of you) often takes so much more time and effort than doing it over. Look into retopo workflows using shinkwrap and other available tools (... use your favorite search engine for those). You should aim to re-do this using quads and avoid non-planar faces. Topology is not a wrapper to put on top of the object. Topology is your object.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18203/is-there-a-way-to-rescue-mesh-that-has-very-bad-topology/18204#18204

Comment: Here's a resource on [Topology Guides](https://topologyguides.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Select all the vertices in edit mode and then

> v2.79 and below

click <kbd>spacebar</kbd> in viewport and type in "Remove Doubles" in the search.

> v2.8+

click <kbd>F3</kbd> in viewport and type in "Merge by distance" in the search.

(or)

You can use this software called "Instant Mesh" by *wjakob* by loading the exported mesh file into this software and get a clean mesh.

link https://github.com/wjakob/instant-meshes

Hope this helps you!

Comment: The spacebar causes Blender 3.6 to start cycling through the frames? I'm confused.

Comment: for v2.8+ you can try presssing F3 and search for "Merge by distance", space is for playing and pausing animation keyframes.

Answer (score 0):

Check this video, it may help:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s2Df3C3_IYE

Answer (score 0):

In Blender 3.2 what worked for me was in *Edit Mode*, select the internal overlapping vertices, right click and select option *Dissolve*.