# I'm searching retopology tools

Tags: mesh, topology

What are the best free-blender tools in order to retopology a mesh? I'm using Mira tool during this period but i don't like it very much. Any advice? Please help me

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36525/how-to-easily-make-mesh-retopology , http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6253/how-to-convert-from-high-poly-to-low-poly

Comment: Thank you for the link but I have already seen that question . . . there isn't another free tools?

Comment: Retopoflow would be the best option, if paying for it is too hard you can find the source on github.