# Triangles forming in a mesh with no triangles when rendering

Tags: modeling, rendering, mesh

it appears in both in cycles and blender render, there´s no difference between the preview and final render, whats causing it?, i don´t have triangles in my geometry[image]

Comment: It's possible also that the faces are non-planar. To check it select all, and choose *Mesh* > *Clean-Up* > *Split Non-planar faces*. If something changes with mesh then that's (one of) reasons. Most likely you will need to [retopologize](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6253/how-to-convert-from-high-poly-to-low-poly) mesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in a simple plain, when you move a vertex in a way that it can't be in a same height with other edges, blender creates an edge between edges to keep your shape as it is.
Take a look at this:
[image]
There is couple of ways to fix it, First you can add a little bit `bevel` to the mesh and then a `subdivision` to give blender more edges to play with(easier to do but heavier mesh).
Or you can add `triangulate` modifier and do some "edge rotate" on edges that you want to be in other direction. (lighter mesh but harder to do)

Comment: thanks a lot, the bevel and subdiv solved it, it was as simple as that, thanks again for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try removing doubles by selecting all and pressing <kbd>w</kbd> then remove doubles.

Also,you have ngons which is automatically converted into triangles when rendering,so if it is not flat it will appear like this,

Comment: thanks for the insight, im a noob at blender and i was trying some hardsurface modelling,  someone told me ngons doesn´t have a lot of impact in hard surface, i´ll have to polish my technique

Answer (score 0):

You can select the object, then go to it's mesh data properties. Then to Normals and turn on auto smooth. This will remove the triangulated mesh. Also set the auto smooth value accordingly.
Hope this helps.