# How to decrease the polygon count on my mesh?

Tags: polycount

I'm an absolute beginner. I'm trying to reduce the count of polygons in my mesh.

I've looked at some tutorials online and I know what I need to do is go through the decimate process.

I can't locate the decimate function on my interface.
Can someone please show me how to find the "decimate" menu in my interface. The interface is unedited from the stock install.

Comment: Relevant questions: [How to easily make mesh retopology](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36525/how-to-easily-make-mesh-retopology) and [How to convert from high poly to low poly](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6253/how-to-convert-from-high-poly-to-low-poly)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simple answer is **Mesh** > **Clean up** > **Decimate Geometry**.

Then look in the bottom of the **Tools panel** to see the Decimate options and reduce the **Ratio**.

[image]

A better, non destructive option is to use the **Decimate Modifier**

You will find more options there.

[image]

There seems to be an option which tries to keep UV maps intact which would be important if your mesh is using those.

[image]